# Получить значение в JSON от процедуры на PL\SQL (БД Oracle) и распарсить его на PHP

Tags: php, oracle

Есть процедура `procedure some_procedure(id in integer, data_json out varchar2)` , которая берет некоторый параметр и возвращает значения в строке формата JSON.
я пытаюсь получить эту строку на php:

```
$sql = "begin some_procedure(:ID,  :JSON);end;";  
    try{  
      $i=0; //ID  
      $arr[$i]['name']='ID';  
      $arr[$i]['val']=$id;  
      $arr[$i]['len']=10;  

      $i=0;
      $res[$i]['name']='JSON';
      $res[$i]['len']=1000;

      $res=db_call_func($sql, $arr, $res, $conn);    
      var_dump($res["JSON"]);    
      $error = oci_error($res['stmt'])['message'];    
       if($error){  
         var_dump('error = ');  
         var_dump($error);  
       }    
     }catch(Exception $exc) {
      var_dump($exc->getMessage());
    } 


  function db_call_func($sql,$arr=null,$res=null, $conn){
    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);
    foreach ($arr as $a){
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":".$a['name'], $a['val'], $a['len']);
    }
    $resarr = [];
    foreach ($res as $r){
      oci_bind_by_name($stmt, ":".$r['name'], $resarr[$r['name']], $r['len']);
    }
    oci_execute($stmt);    
    oci_commit($conn);
    $resarr['stmt']=$stmt;   
    return $resarr;   
  }
```

в итоге при var_dump($res["JSON"]) получаю NULL. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что я делаю не так и как это поправить?

Comment: что такое db_call_func (это явно не стандартная функция php) и что она делает в случае ошибки. надо проверить на ошибку БД и вывести ее, если она есть. тем более, что мне вот этот begin кажется мягко говоря странным, у oracle процедуры так не вызываются

Comment: немного подправила код. db_call_func приведен чуть ниже запроса. $conn - это строка с подключением к БД.  Другие запросы данной функцией обрабатываются

Comment: oci_error($res['stmt'])['message']; не возвращает ошибку, результатом выполнения функции в том виде, в котором она представлена в вопросе, будет null, хотя при вызове функции в TOAD результат не NULL, строка вида "{'value1':12; 'value2':21}". Это может быть как-то связано с экранированием символов в возвращаемом значении?

Comment: сомневаюсь. данным все равно что в них содержится, в привязанную переменную они должны класться как есть. но как oci функции работают с возвращаемыми параметрами я не в курсе, никогда с этим не сталкивался

Comment: Решение проблемы не удалось найти, поэтому  процедура на SQL переписана так, чтобы она сохраняла данные во временную таблицу, а потом уже обычным запросом эти данные забираю в PHP. Главное при этом использовать для вызова процедуры и запроса данных одно и тоже соединение (oci_connect)